# Xcode version is different to the version listed in my App Store applications

Tags: xcode

I recently updated Xcode to version 6.4. In the App Store it says I have version 6.4 installed, but when I run Xcode it says version 6.3.2.

Does anyone know how I run Xcode version 6.4? Do I need to uninstall and then reinstall Xcode?

I installed it using the App Store and updated through the App Store as well.

Comment: Where is Xcode saying it's 6.3.2? In Help > About?

Comment: Yes, in Help > About and also on the Welcome to Xcode screen which can be found in Window -> Welcome to Xcode if a project is open

Comment: Well then you are running Xcode 6.3.2.  However it's possible to have multiple versions of Xcode installed; they just need to be installed into different folders or they need to be renamed.  You'll have to investigate that yourself as you could have basically done anything to confuse this situation.

Answer (score 0):

So while I was unable to find out where Xcode 6.3.2 or 6.4 was installed on my mac, I uninstalled Xcode by dragging the application to the trash can and emptying it as recommended by Apple.

I then reinstalled Xcode 6.4 from the App Store and it appears to be working.

While it is a simple thing, I thought I would share as sometimes the simple solutions are the ones we don't think about.